# Custom RGB ColorModel

Tags: java, rgb, color-space

I have a program that displays RGB images (internally represented as int[]s) on the screen. I want to be able to adjust the parameters that are used to map an in-memory value (e.g. a red intensity of 128) to an on-screen value. For example, I want to be able to say "max intensity (1.0) for red corresponds to a pixel value of 50; min intensity (0.0) corresponds to 4". And of course adjust the green and blue components as well.

From what I can tell, this requires me to make a custom `ColorModel`, perhaps a subclass of `PackedColorModel`. Currently I'm using a `DirectColorModel`, which does not appear to be adjustable (it always maps 0 for a component to 0 on the display, and 255 to 1.0 on the display). Worse, for some reason its methods are final so I can't create a custom variant of `DirectColorModel` with different rules.

Unfortunately, `PackedColorModel` does not appear to be remotely trivial to subclass. In addition to leaving a huge number of methods abstract, its constructor takes a `ColorSpace`, the only implementation of which is `ICC_ColorSpace`, which in turn requires an `ICC_Profile`. If I were trying to do some kind of photography work, then maybe I would be interested in this level of detail, but my needs are not so complicated; I just want to be able to vary the intensity scaling of the R/G/B components in my image data.

Is there some reasonably straightforward way to achieve what I'm trying to do, or do I really have to leap down the rabbit hole and build a complex system just to do some basic color adjustment in a reasonably performant fashion?

I've done similar things in the past using OpenGL calls, but unfortunately that's not an option here, since ultimately the rendering code is outside of my control; I can only adjust the color model used by a `Graphics.drawImage()` call.

Thanks for your time!